# Does equivalence of categories preserve equivalence relations?

Tags: category-theory

Let $F:\mathscr{A}\longrightarrow \mathscr{B}$ be (a part of) an equivalence of categories. My questions are:

1) Does $F$ preserve equivalence relations?

2) Does $F$ reflect equivalence relations?

I recall my definition of an equivalence relation. An equivalence relation on an object $M$ of a category $\mathscr{A}$ is a triple $(R,r_1,r_2)$, where $R$ is an object of $\mathscr{A}$ and $(r_1,r_2)$ is a pair of monomorphic arrows $r_1,r_2:R\longrightarrow M$, that is for every object $X$ and every pair of arrows $r_1,r_2:X\longrightarrow R$, we have $x=y$ iff $r_1\circ x=r_1\circ y$ and $r_2\circ x=r_2\circ y$.

Moreover, for every $X$ in $\mathscr{A}$,

$$R_X=\{(r_1\circ x,r_2\circ x): x\in\mathscr{A}(X,R)\}\subseteq\mathscr{A}(X,M)\times\mathscr{A}(X,M)$$
is an equivalence relation (reflexive, symmetric, transitive) on $\mathscr{A}(X,M)$ in the category of sets.

Comment: Yes, of course it does. What makes you doubt it?

Comment: What you describe sounds like a binary relation to me. Surely you want to require more to justify the name "equivalence relation"?

Comment: @AlexKruckman yes, I've edited.

Comment: @ZhenLin Actually, I've proved this fact, but my proof looks too long and intricate, so I was looking for an easier one. As you said, it should be "obvious", but I can't see it.

Comment: It is more or less immediate if you use the hom-set definition. After all, $F : \mathcal{A} (X, M) \to \mathcal{B} (F X, F M)$ is a bijection.